# Wordpress: Search items in table

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have created a test page in which users can access pdf and word documents.

site: http://recordandreturn2.insctest1.com/online-forms

The default search feature on the wordpress site does not bring up any of the items once you have typed them in. Example, Search "Affidavit of Heirship". I am using a plugin called easy table as the client will need to easily add or remove items moving forward. I have searched for wordpress search functionality enhancers, but nothing seems to work.

this example site has a search feature that brings up forms, this is what I want to achieve: http://www.judicialtitle.com/resources/forms

Comment: Are the Documents information stored in a Plugin specific table or a Wordpress Table?

Comment: @Musk they are stored in the default wordpress media, and reference in the plugin called easy table

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-table

Comment: What you would need basicly is change the query before it is sent and add the specified data you are looking for. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/  ,  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: @Musk im fairly new to this. can you go into this further? I am currently looking at the documentation you have linked.

Comment: Looking at the plugin i'm suprised it doesnt have a search support other than what i see here. https://ps.w.org/easy-table/assets/screenshot-2.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin capable of searching shortcodes:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-search/

Alternatively, you can add the following to functions.php to include shortcodes in your searches

```
<?php
//Replace wp_trim_excerpt with a commented out strip_shortcodes()
function improved_trim_excerpt($text) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');

        //$text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
        } else {
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }
    return apply_filters('improved_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_trim_excerpt');

//You might also need to add this in order to make sure the 
//shortcodes are actually parsed and not just displayed
//$text = do_shortcode($text);
?>
```

This code is from `http://3rdplanetwebsolutions.com/news/add-shortcode-content-to-wordpress-search-results/`

Comment: awesome i'll try this out. im still fairly new to this. where it says to replace wp_trim_excerpt , i'll sub in the short code for the Easy Table wordpress plugin?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-table/

Comment: No, that's just explaining what the code does. You don't need to edit anything.